# SQLCipher executable not working on macOS

Tags: database, macos, sqlite, sqlcipher

I try to compile and run SQLCipher on macOS, but it's not working.

What did I do wrong? And are there any useless actions?

1) **OpenSSL build**

- Download and extract archive of OpenSSL v1.0.2 last version sources
  (https://www.openssl.org/source)
- Create folder "/usr/local/lib/openssl-1.0.2"
- Build with commands:

-

```
$ ./Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc shared --openssldir=/usr/local/lib/openssl-1.0.2
$ make depend
$ sudo make install
```

Files are in folder "/usr/local/lib/openssl-1.0.2/lib"

2) **SQLite build**

- Download and extract archive of SQLite last version sources with
  script "configure" and makefiles TEA
  (https://www.sqlite.org/download.html)
- Create folder "/usr/local/lib/sqlite-3.22.0"
- Build with commands:

-

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/lib/sqlite-3.22.0
$ make
$ make install
```

Files are in folder "/usr/local/lib/sqlite-3.22.0/lib"

3) **SQLCipher build**

- Download and extract archive of SQLCipher last version sources on
  Github project releases
  (https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher/releases)
- Build with commands:

-

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/lib/sqlcipher-3.4.2 --enable-tempstore=yes CFLAGS="-DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC" LDFLAGS="/usr/local/lib/openssl-1.0.2/lib/libcrypto.a"
$ make clean
$ make
$ make install
```

4) **Run test**

- Copy build file "/usr/local/lib/sqlcipher-3.4.2/bin/sqlcipher" on
  test folder "/Users/user/Documents/sqlcipher-test"
- Copy files "/usr/local/lib/sqlcipher-3.4.2/lib/libsqlcipher*",
  "/usr/local/lib/sqlite-3.22.0/lib/libsqlite3*" and
  "/usr/local/lib/openssl-1.0.2/lib/libcrypto*" on test folder "/Users/user/Documents/sqlcipher-test"
- Test folder "/Users/user/Documents/sqlcipher-test" contains: 'sqlcipher' (exec), 'libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib', 'libcrypto.a', 'libcrypto.dylib', 'libsqlcipher.0.dylib', 'libsqlcipher.a', 'libsqlcipher.dylib', 'libsqlcipher.la', 'libsqlite3.0.dylib', 'libsqlite3.a', 'libsqlite3.dylib' and 'libsqlite3.la'
- Change command line folder to test folder (`cd "/Users/user/Documents/sqlcipher-test"`)
- Create new SQLite plaintext database

-

```
$ ./sqlcipher plaintext.db
$ sqlite> create table testtable (id integer, name text);
$ sqlite> insert into testtable (id,name) values(1,'Bob');
$ sqlite> insert into testtable (id,name) values(2,'Charlie');
$ sqlite> insert into testtable (id,name) values(3,'Daphne');
$ sqlite> select * from testtable;
$ sqlite> .exit
```

- Open plaintext.db file with a standard text-editor: database scheme
  and test data can be read in plaintext
- Create new SQLCipher encrypted database

-

```
$ ./sqlcipher plaintext.db
$ sqlite> ATTACH DATABASE 'encrypted.db' AS encrypted KEY 'testkey';
```

**"Error: unable to open database: encrypted.db"**

**"encrypted.db" file is empty**

See https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-api/ for more informations

Comment: Have you tried using homebrew @romainb78?(if you don't know what it is, it is a package manager for MacOS).

Comment: Ok thanks, I installed Homebrew (see [Homebrew website](https://brew.sh)) and I installed SQLCipher with Homebrew (`$ brew install sqlcipher`). But it's a pity that I can't use it correctly by compiling it directly from its sources.

Comment: I have tried to compile many other things on Mac but only `homebrew` works for me @romainb78.

Comment: Try deleting encrypted.db, and ensuring that it does not exist before running the attach statement.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work!